# Disabling Nvidia card on Asus UL30JT

Tags: nvidia, laptop, asus

I'm a new Linux user, and I recently installed Ubuntu on my Asus UL30JT. The PC runs quite hot, and I randomly stumbled upon this: http://www.grimsby.us/ubuntu-on-asus-ul30vt/

From what I understand, my Nvidia card is probably still on and using power, and probably also creating excess heat? Anyway, I was not able to use the method presented on that page. I tried installing the linked software, but it ended in an error.

How do I disable my Nvidia card?

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime

After installed enter the nvidia control panel and change the settings.